# How to disable select option if input number is greater than?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this html:

```
<input id="numberInput" name="numberInput"/>

<select>
 <option>Some text</option>
 <option class="" id="disableThis">Some text 2</option>
 <option>Some text 3</option>
</select>
```

and Javascript code:

```
$("#numberInput").on("change", function() {
var x = 20;
if ((Number("#numberInput")) > Number(x)) {
    var d = document.getElementById("disableThis");
    d.className = "hidden";
}
});
```

I am trying to disable this specific select option if a person inputs a number in the input field greater than 20, but can't seem to figure it out how to do it.

Here's the live code https://jsfiddle.net/qxqg32rk/

How can I do this?

Comment: is this hard coded and not using any backend language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#numberInput").on("change", function() {
var x = 20;
if ($(this).val() > Number(x)) {
    $('#disableThis').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
} else {
    $('#disableThis').prop('disabled', false);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberInput" name="numberInput"/>

<select>
 <option>Some text</option>
 <option class="" id="disableThis">Some text 2</option>
 <option>Some text 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#numberInput").on("change", function() {
    var x = 20;
    var value = $(this).val();
    if (value > x) {
        $("#disableThis").attr("disabled","disabled")
    }else{
        $("#disableThis").removeAttr("disabled","disabled")
    }
});
```

Comment: [.removeAttr()](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) only accepts one argument. You should use: `$("#disableThis").remoteAttr("disabled");`

Answer (score 0):

Problems with your code

1. Assigning a "hidden" classname is not how you disable a select box. You have to set the disable property as true. Like this `document.getElementById('disableThis').disabled = true;`
2. `Number("#numberInput")` won't give you the value of that input box. You have to use `$("#numberInput").val()` for that

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qxqg32rk/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the value with the `.val()` method to get the value and use `.addClass()` method to add the class to your element:

```
$("#numberInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var x = 20;
  if (Number($("#numberInput").val()) > Number(x)) {
    $("#disableThis").addClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$("#numberInput").on("keyup", function() {
  var x = 20;
  if (Number($("#numberInput").val()) > Number(x)) {
    $("#disableThis").addClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberInput" name="numberInput" />

<select>
 <option>Some text</option>
 <option class="" id="disableThis">Some text 2</option>
 <option>Some text 3</option>
</select>
```

**Note:**

Note that I used `keyup` ebvent with the input to give an immediate live effect in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `attr` property

```
$("#numberInput").on("change", function() {
var x = 20;
if ((Number("#numberInput")) > Number(x)) {
     $("#disableThis").attr("disabled",true);
}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

To get `numberInput` value you should use `val()` function. In your `if` instead of adding class hiden you can also use `hide()` function

```js
$("#numberInput").on("change", function() {
 
    var x = 20;
    if ($("#numberInput").val() > x) {
        $("#disableThis").hide();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="numberInput" name="numberInput"/>

<select>
  <option>Some text</option>
  <option class="" id="disableThis">Some text 2</option>
  <option>Some text 3</option>
</select>
```